# Interface/pattern etc

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, interface

I need to get an understanding of how to use an interface so that common methods among the implementing classes can be grouped together.

The obvious approach is to have an abstract class implementing the interface and the child classes inheriting from this class. Would this not violate the whole concept of programming to an interface?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what is exactly voilated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Interface is a contract with your client. You offer certain capabilities. The client thinks only in terms of the Interface and need have no interest in how your class or classes implement that Interface.

The Abstract class, is an implementation technique to allow you to refactor some common code from you implemntations of the Interface. As this does not obstruct the use of the Interface there's no violation.

You might use a Factory pattern to hide the details of the implementation from the user:

```
 Interface myWorker = TheFactory.make( {some expression of the client's needs } );
```

All the client sees is the factory and the interface.

So Interface is for clients, Abstract class is for implementors.